# Existence of eigenvalue when domain and codomain are different

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I came across this statement: Let V be a complex vector space. If $T:V\rightarrow V$ is a linear transformation, then $T$ has a (complex) eigenvalue. I believe this is a direct consequence of fundamental theorem of algebra. But I was wondering whether $V \rightarrow V$ is necessary (i.e. is the statement true if $T: V\rightarrow S$, where S is not a subspace of $V$?)? 
I think it's not true in general because the basis is different. My counterexample in mind is a 90-degree rotation of the x-axis. Then with respect to the standard basis, the eigenvector seems to be 1. But surely the vector changed after the transformation.
I was wondering if this is a valid counterexample? And in general, when we talk about eigenvalue/eigenvector of a linear transformation, do we assume $T:V\rightarrow V$?
Thank you!

Comment: $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue if the map $T-\lambda I$ is not injective. How would you define an eigenvalue for an operator from $V$ to a different space?

Comment: I just realised - is it not even defined? @Mark

Comment: The statement is not true for infinite-dimensional vector spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In linear algebra, one usually defines eigenalues and eigenvectors only for linear transformations from a space to itself.  However, in functional analysis one considers unbounded linear operators that are only defined on a subspace of a vector space, and there one does consider eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I don't know functional analysis yet but will come back to your comments when I take it!